# Laravel Update Function Don't Save New Data

Tags: php, laravel

So I have trouble updating data from edit form. I tried to use 'dd' and it's collect all the data it needs. No error, but the data on database not change.

```
public function update(Request $request, Stationery $stationery)
{
    $validated =  $request->validate([
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'nama' => 'required',
        'satuan' => 'nullable',
        'harga' => 'required',
        'keterangan' => 'nullable'
    ]);
    // dd($validated);

    Stationery::where('id', $stationery->id)
        ->update($validated);
    return redirect('/barang/pakaihabis')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Diubah!!');
}
```

The success message pop out but the data still same.

The only protected in the model Stationery

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

Comment: Maybe model Stationery have some trouble? Can You add protected variables to question?

Comment: That's what I thought too. I only use $guarded = ['id'] but I did try to use $fillable but it doesn't work.
Already add it to the question.

Comment: The most likely problem is that you are not getting the model passed into your function.  `dd($stationery)` and check that it is the one you expected.

Comment: I did that and all of the data needed is there. Which is why I'm confused why it won't update the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```php
$stationery->update($validated);
```

There is no need for `where` because you use route model binding ;)

Comment: Someone also told me to do this and I tried but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. This one should work